# BOCU-1 for internal encoding of strings

Tags: unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, utf-16, non-ascii-characters

Some languages/platforms like Java, Javascript, Windows, Dotnet, KDE etc. use UTF16. Some others prefer UTF8.

What is the reason that no language/platform uses [BOCU-1](https://www.unicode.org/notes/tn6/)? What is the rationale for [JEP 254](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/254) and [JEP 254 equivalent for Dotnet](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/6612)?

Is the reason that BOCU-1 is patented? Are there any technical reasons also?

---

Edit

My question is not about Java specifically. By JEP 254, I mean compact UTF-16 as mentioned in that proposal. My question is, since BOCU-1 is compact for almost any unicode string, why don't any language/platform use it internally, instead of UTF-16 or UTF-8. Such a usage would improve cache performance for any string, and not just ASCII or Latin-1.

Such a usage may also help in non-Latin programming language support in formats like [The Language Server Index Format (LSIF)](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/02/19/lsif).

Comment: JEP 254 says "Non-Goals —
It is not a goal to use alternate encodings such as UTF-8 in the internal representation of strings. A subsequent JEP may explore that approach."  I think that 'such as' would include BOCU-1.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Please see my edit.

Comment: Seen — but I've no idea what the answer to your question is.  I had to search for BOCU-1 to find out anything about it.  The royalty-free license suggests that there shouldn't be a problem with the patent, though it does place the onus on a developer using BOCU-1 to get the license from IBM.  I'm a little concerned that the answers to the question will be 'opinion-based', which is one of the reasons for closing questions on SO.  I've not flagged it for closure (for any reason), but be aware that some people might consider that option.

Comment: Well, for one thing, BOCU-1 is more of a *compression scheme* than a Unicode *byte encoding*. It would be less inefficient to have to keep decompressing a compressed string, for instance, when accessing/enumerating individual characters in the string. Compact strings in JEP 254, for instance, don't use compression, they simply use a smaller byte encoding (Latin-1) to save space when possible. Indexing into a string's UTF-16 interface using Latin-1 backend storage is fairly straight forward, but indexing a string's UTF-16 interface using a compressed backend storage is not so much.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Do you have any research paper to cite your denial of the [official position of the Unicode consortium](https://www.unicode.org/notes/tn6/#Performance)? In fact, for many scripts like South Asian, Persian, Cyrillic etc., BOCU-1 <-> UTF16 is more performant than UTF8  <-> UTF16. The test machine was a Pentium 2 laptop, so today's machines may do the compression with performance as you mentioned.

Comment: @JayadevanVijayan That performance comparison (and yes, I did read that before posting my previous comment) is for converting whole strings from one encoding to another. That is not what I was referring to in my previous comment.

Comment: Seeing the responses so far, my assumption is that no one in the world has yet published a paper comparing the amount (as percentage of RAM) of strings belonging to different Unicode blocks and the impact these have on cache hits, based on various encodings, in various typical settings. Probably the answer is then: More research is needed.

Comment: Regarding _"Seeing the responses so far, **my assumption is that no one in the world has yet published a paper**... "_, that is a very rash assumption to draw based on a handful of comments.

Comment: As it stands your (interesting) question is violating SO guidelines in at least three ways: [1] It is inviting opinion based answers. [2] It asks four distinct questions. [3] It is very broad, and lacks focus. Can you reword it accordingly?

Comment: @skomisa Can you please edit the question to make this more useful for readers of stackoverflow? English is not my native language.

Comment: @skomisa String compactness has direct impact on performance. Please see [this](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~shade/density/state-of-string-density-v1.txt) and [this](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~huntch/string-density/reports/String-Density-SPARC-jbb2005-Report.pdf). (1) I was asking for facts. BOCU-1 seems to be the most compact (and thus the most cache-friendly). This can be tested empirically. (2) The question is "What is the reason that no language/platform uses BOCU-1?". All the rest is explanation of that question. (3) The question is about why not BOCU-1 is used.

Comment: OK. I have attempted to answer your questions, and although BOCU-1 now seems doomed I did not find any specific reason why it was never adopted in the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the reason that no language/platform uses BOCU-1?

That question is far too broad in scope for Stack Overflow, and a concise answer is impossible.

However, in the specific case of Java note that someone raised the possibility of Java adopting BOCU-1 as an RFE (Request For Enhancement) in 2002. See [JDK-4787935 (str) Reducing the memory footprint for Strings](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4787935).

That bug was closed with a resolution of "*Won't Fix*" ten years later:

*"Although this is a very interesting proposal, **it is highly unlikely that BOCU** or any other multi-byte encoding for internal use **would be adopted**. Furthermore, this comes down to a space-time tradeoff with unclear long-term consequences. Given the length of time this proposal has lingered, it seems appropriate to close it as will not fix"*.

> What is the rationale for JEP 254...?

There is a section of JEP 254 titled "*Motivation*" which explains that, and in particular it states "*most String objects contain only Latin-1 characters*". However, if that does not satisfy you, raise a separate question.

Ensure that it is on topic for Stack Overflow by reviewing [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) first. Two of the people who reviewed JEP 254 (Aleksey Shipilev and Brian Goetz) respond here on SO, so you may get an authoritative answer.

> What is the rationale for ... JEP 254 equivalent for Dotnet?

Again, raise this as a separate SO question.

> Is the reason that BOCU-1 is patented?

[That question is specifically off topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"Legal questions, including questions about copyright or licensing, are off-topic for Stack Overflow"*, though [Wikipedia notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_Ordered_Compression_for_Unicode#Patent) "*BOCU-1 is the only Unicode compression scheme described on the Unicode Web site that is known to be encumbered with intellectual property restrictions*".

> Are there any technical reasons also?

A very important non-technical reason is that [the HTML5 specification explicitly forbids the use of BOCU-1](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-choosing-encodings)!...

```
Avoid these encodings

The HTML5 specification calls out a number of encodings that you should avoid...

Documents must also not use CESU-8, UTF-7, BOCU-1, or SCSU encodings, since they... were never intended for Web content and the HTML5 specification forbids browsers from recognising them.
```

Of course that invites the question of *why* HTML 5 forbids the use of BOCU-1, and the only technical reason I can find for that is that [this Mozilla documentation on HTML's `<meta>` element states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta):

```
Authors must not use CESU-8, UTF-7, BOCU-1 and/or SCSU as cross-site scripting attacks with these encodings have been demonstrated.
```

[See this GitHub link](https://github.com/cure53/XSSChallengeWiki/wiki/Cure53-Singapore-Training-Challenge) for more details on the XSS vulnerability with BOCU-1.

Also note that in line with the the HTML5 specification, all the major browsers specifically do not support BOCU-1.